# How to Remove Vuex State data

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am using `vuex` in my E-commerce website to keep shopping cart items in storage to use in every page. I used `vuex-persistedstate` to keep data and its succussed. But I can't remove them from local storage.Anyone can slove this ?

**My Store index.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';

Vue.use(Vuex);

import state from "./state";
import * as getters from "./getters";
import * as mutations from "./mutations";
import * as actions from "./actions";

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state, 
    getters, 
    mutations,
    actions,
    plugins: [createPersistedState()],
    
});
```

**Vuex State**

[image]

Comment: Try using vuex-persistedstate API `createPersistedState([options])` which comprise of `setState` option which will help you to set it back to empty array or string.

Comment: can you please elaborate more how to use `setState` option

Comment: https://dev.to/nickitax/persistent-store-with-vuejs-vuex-and-vuex-persisted-state-354n